# Add custom link near search box in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, header, headerlink

I already check many answers regarding move `header.links` to `page.top` its working but the problem is that its also move my custom links to header content.

that's why I remove `greeting message`, `Sign in`, `Create an account` & add custom links to the top menu, but now I did not found any solution to add `sign in`, `Create an account` link & `Greeting message` into the header-content or near the search box.

I tried by creating default.xml into app/design/.../Magento_Theme/layout, but its not working, I added custom link by module, so please give me solution which can achieve by module.

Here is my default.xml

File Path:

> app/code/vendor/modulename/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
 <body>
    <referenceBlock name="header.links">

        <!-- Contact us Link -->
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="contactus.link" after="register-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">Contact Us</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">contact-us</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>

        <!-- CMS Page Link Link -->
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="aboutus.link" after="contactus.link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">About Us</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">about-us</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>

        <!-- CMS Page Link Link -->
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="customerservice.link" after="customerservice.link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">Customer Service</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">customer-service</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>

        <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />           
        <referenceBlock name="authorization-link-login" remove="true" />      
        <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />          
        <referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true" />
    </referenceBlock>

</body>
```

I also tried add link by using page.top but its shows link below the `header-content`.

Comment: You can also achieve the default way: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/299257/how-to-move-existing-links-and-add-new-custom-links-in-top-header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a block & add a link into phtml file.

add code into default.xml

```
    <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="linkboxes"  template="SimpleMagento_HeaderChange::headerlink.phtml" after="header.panel.wrapper"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

use `header-wrapper` to get the link between logo & search box.

headerlink.phtml

```
.dropdown .logout {
    position: static;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 6px;
    float: right;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

Use CSS  as per your need

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$wishlist = $objectManager->create('Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist');
$wishlistObj = $wishlist->loadByCustomerId($customerSession->getCustomerId())->getItemCollection();

if ($wishlistObj) {
$count = $wishlistObj->getSize();
}

if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) : ?>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <span><?php echo "Welcome, ".$customerSession->getCustomer()->getName()."! ▼" ?></span>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a class= "header_account_link" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl("customer/account");?>"><?php echo __('My Account')?></a>
                <br>
                <a class= "header_account_link" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl("wishlist");?>"><?php echo __('My Wish List')." " ?></a><span>(<?= $count ?> items)</span>
                <br>
                <a class= "header_account_link" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl("customer/account/logout");?>"><?php echo __('Logout')?></a>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php else: ?>
        <div class="logout">
            <span class="header_account_link_list login">
                <a class= "header_account_link" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl("customer/account/login");?>"><?php echo __('Sign in')?></a>
            </span> &nbsp; &nbsp;
            <span class="header_account_link_list login">
                <a class= "header_account_link" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl("customer/account/create");?>"><?php echo __('Create an account')?></a>
            </span>
        </div>
 <?php endif;?>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "customer": {
                    "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```